# Any video lecture on copula function, a statistics concept for measuring dependence?

Tags: copula

I have read the paper ['Coping with copulas'](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228876267_Coping_with_copulas) and it is a bit hard for me to read since it has lots of mathematical equations.

So I am looking for any video lecture on this topic, copula function. I don't care if it's from a statistics department or finance department. I have checked Coursera, many universities' OCW websites, and Youtube but could not find a decent introductory level lectures.

Maybe a book or an academic paper about it is okay, as long as it's easy to read and not so math-heavy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very difficult to find accessible material on copulas. I'm still struggling to understand them myself. While I haven't come across any videos that explain copulas well, I have found the following resources very helpful.

A blog post: [An intuitive, visual guide to copulas](https://twiecki.io/blog/2018/05/03/copulas/), by Thomas Wiecki, is truly introductory with absolute minimal math but it doesn't go into much detail.

A paper: [A Short, Comprehensive, Practical Guide to Copulas](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1847864), by Attilio Meucci, is more rigorous and more challenging but worth the extra effort

Answer (score 1):

I am sharing what I found most helpful for understanding the concept 'copula'. It is an academic paper written by an undergraduate student in Netherland, for her college graduation in 2007.

[Copulas: modeling dependencies in Financial Risk Management](https://www.math.vu.nl/~sbhulai/papers/paper-habiboellah.pdf)

This paper started with why measuring dependencies among financial assets is critical and continued with the downsides of correlation, which is the most popular measure for dependency. And then introduce copula correcting those downsides of correlation.

The best educational material for understanding copula, so far.

Answer (score 0):

Just searching youtube immediately turns up tons of videos with lectures about copulas. Here is a sampling https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sB_M1U-8-Hw https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XzfvUaL45cg https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z43_pf5Y6A8 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BDjw4r1ylS4 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_tCbifQBdYE and there are many more.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have checked all of the videos that you have mentioned, but what I found was that all of them either (1) briefly touch upon the concept 'copula' without enough build-up before introducing the concept copula or (2) lack the high-level (or kind) explanation of what the mathematical formula means...Thanks for your kind answer

Comment: I was expecting something more like (1) coursera courses or (2) MIT opencoureware things, with enough introductory materials